# How to add functions to some jQuery objects, but not others?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Let's say I have a `<ul>` list:

```
<ul class="products">
    ...
</ul>
```

I want to select it with jQuery, then add some functions to that object. For example, I'd like to add an `addProduct(productData)` function and a `deleteProduct(productId)` function. However, I'd like the functions to only be added to the object that's returned by the selector. So for example, something like this:

```
var productList = $.extend($('ul.products'), {
    addProduct: function(productData) {
        // add a new li item
    },
    deleteProduct: function(productId) {
        // delete li with id
    }
});
```

How would I do this using jQuery? The key point here is that I only want to add the functions to an instance returned by a jQuery selector. In other words, I don't want to modify jQuery's prototype or create a plugin, since those will make the functions available across everything, whereas I only want to add the functions to one specific instance.

Comment: Can I ask what the final aim of this methodology is?

Comment: I'd like to be able to method chain it, for example `$('ul.products').fadeIn().addProduct(data);`. Also, it keeps it consistent with how other jQuery methods are called.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you only want the `addProduct` and `deleteProduct` methods to feature on that *single* jQuery object, then what you've got will work fine; but you'll have to keep a reference to that jQuery object/ only use it once, to preserve the existance of the `addProduct` and `deleteProduct` methods.

However, these `addProduct` and `deleteProduct` methods are unique to that particular jQuery object; the methods won't exist on any other jQuery objects you create;

```
var productList = $.extend($('ul.products'), {
    addProduct: function(productData) {
        // add a new li item
    },
    deleteProduct: function(productId) {
        // delete li with id
    }
});

// Using this particular jQuery object (productList) will work fine.
productList.addProduct();
productList.removeProduct();

// However, addProduct() does not exist on new jQuery objects, even if they use
// the same selector.
$('ul.products').addProduct(); // error; [object Object] has no method 'addProduct'
```

The best way do to this would be to go-back-to-basics and define separate `addProduct` and `deleteProduct` functions, which accept a jQuery object. If you wanted to restrict these functions to they only worked on the `ul.products` selector, you could do;

```
function addProduct(obj) {
    obj = obj.filter('ul.products');

    // do something with `obj` (its a jQuery object)
}
```

This approach would be recommended as it keeps the `jQuery.fn` API consistent; otherwise you'd be adding `addProduct` and `removeProduct` to *some* `jQuery.fn` instances but not others, or making their usage redundant in others. With this approach however `addProduct` and `removeProduct` are always there, but don't get in anyones way if they don't want to use them.

---

## Historical Notes

This answer was originally written in November 2011, when jQuery 1.7 was released. Since then the API has changed considerably. The answer above is relevant to the *current* 2.0.0 version of jQuery.

Prior to 1.9, a little used method called [`jQuery.sub`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.sub/) used to exist, which is *related* to what you're trying to do (but won't help you unless you change your approach). This creates a new jQuery constructor, so you could do;

```
var newjQuery = jQuery.sub();
newjQuery.fn.addProduct = function () {
    // blah blah
};
newjQuery.fn.deleteProduct = function () {
    // blah blah
};

var foo = newjQuery('ul.products');
foo.deleteProduct();
foo.addProduct();

var bar = jQuery('ul.products');
bar.deleteProduct(); // error
bar.addProduct(); // error
```

Be careful though, the `$` method alias would reference the old `jQuery` object, rather than the `newjQuery` instance.

`jQuery.sub` was removed from jQuery in 1.9. It is now available [as a plugin](http://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/).

Answer (score 6):

You can make your own jQuery methods as follows:

```
$.fn.addProduct = function(){
  var myObject = $(this);
  // do something
}

// Call it like:
$("ul.products").addProduct();
```

This is a bit tricky though because you are making methods that are very specific to lists. So, to be sure you should at least add some checking on the object's type and handle the code correctly if the current object is, let's say an input element.

An alternative is to make a normal Javascript method that receives the list as a parameter. That way you can make a more list specific method.

Comment: This is what I was looking for and it worked as I expected it would/should.. And, it seems to answer the original question nicely.. Why was this down-voted?

Comment: Beats me...I don't see why it's wrong either. But you can upvote if your like. In any case. Glad I could be of any help ;)

Comment: Bit late to the party I know, but the OP said in his question; *However, I'd like the functions to only be added to the object that's returned by the selector.*, rather than all jQuery objects, which is what this answer does... maybe that's the reason for the downvote (although I'm not the downvoter)

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to add a function to that DOM Object.

```
$(function(){
    // [0] gets the first object in array, which is your selected element, you can also use .get(0) in jQuery
    $("#test")[0].addProduct = function(info){
        alert("ID: " + this.id + " - Param: " + info);
    };


    $("#test")[0].addProduct("productid");
});
```

Above script wil alert "ID: test - Param: productid"

A live example: http://jsfiddle.net/jJ65A/1/

Or normal javascript

```
$(function(){
    document.getElementById("test").addProduct = function(info){
        alert(info);
    };
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think may be just using delegate in jQuery:

```
$(".parentclass").delegate("childclass","eventname",function(){});
```

Comment: Either you answered the wrong question, or you didn't read the question... this is of no relevance to what the question is asking.