# How to append Function directly to ID in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, function, append

I have one form where I have to display the same `table thead` multiple times. I thought a solution would be to write the `thead` in single function and call that function wherever I want in my project. For this I write one function:

```
function commonStructure() {
  return append('<thead>
    <tr>name</tr>
    <tr><address></tr>');
  }
```

I am trying to call this function like:

```
$('#classA').commonStructure();
```

This is not working for me. Please help me for the same issue.

Comment: Where exactly is `append()` defined?

Comment: Also this is very confusing.  You have the `commonStructure()` as a stand alone method, not attached to jQuery

Comment: And your appended html is invalid, you are not closing your `thead`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to add functions to some jQuery objects, but not others?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8119851/how-to-add-functions-to-some-jquery-objects-but-not-others)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `commonStructure` function has nothing to do with jQuery. If you want to call it on a jQuery object you need to create it as a plugin. From there you need to amend your `append()` function to work on the element(s) contained in the jQuery object. If all you're doing is adding the content to the DOM, then you can use jQuery's own `append()` method - although `prepend()` would make more sense as you're attempting to create a header.

It's also worth noting that JS strings cannot contain line breaks. Either concatenate them over multiple lines or use template literals (as in the following example). In addition, your HTML is invalid. The content of the `thead` needs to be placed in `td` cells within the `tr`.

Putting it all together it should look something like this:

```js
$.fn.commonStructure = function() {
  return this.prepend(`<thead>
    <tr><td>name</td></tr>
    <tr><td>address</td></tr>
  </thead>`);
};

$('.foo').commonStructure();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table class="foo"></table>
<table class="foo"></table>
```